# How does the two room penalty work in Grand Austria Hotel?

Tags: grand-austria-hotel

One of the Emperor Tiles for Grand Austria Hotel looks like this:

[image]

The [rules](http://lookout-spiele.de/wp-content/uploads/GAH_rules_EN_web.pdf) contain the following explanation for the penalty:

> Penalty: You must remove 2 occupied rooms from your Hotel board. These must be the occupied room in the highest possible row and the next possible room below it, if any.

Does this mean that if I have two occupied rooms in the top row then should I choose which to lose?  Assuming I get to choose which occupied room in the top row I lose then am I allowed to pick based on what's below it?  Finally, if the room below it isn't occupied then do I have to lose a room below that instead? (i.e. does "below" mean "adjacent and below" or "aligned and below"?)

Answer (score 1):

I think the intention here is you must do whats worst for you.

If you have two rooms on the same highest level and one has an occupied room beneath it the you must choose the one where you can lose both.  You would only get a choice if the conditions was met more than once.

Below means 'aligned and below'.   Look at the picture you posted.  The rooms crossed out are in the same aligned column whilst the ones not below are not crossed out.

Comment: By "aligned and below" I was trying to imply that this penalty could skip a row.  So if you have a full room on the left of the top (4th) floor, the room below was empty and the room below that was full then maybe you should lose the rooms from the 2nd and 4th floors?  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: if the wording is next 'possible' room I'd say yes.   I want to play this game but its the only game my friends ever argued about as we couldn't agree on how the passing rules worked.

Comment: The wording does say "possible" yes (I've quoted the rules in the question).

I think I understand how the passing rules work. If you add a question about it then I'm happy to try to answer it.